# How do I use pd.NA by default in pandas DataFrame.from_records?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

pd.NA and related pandas array dtypes are solving some of the most annoying issues with missing data in pandas. How do I use pd.NA by default when creating a DataFrame like this?

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    {'a': 1, 'b': 'x'},
    {'b': 'y', 'c': 1.7},
])

# Pandas 1.2 output
#      a  b    c
# 0  1.0  x  NaN
# 1  NaN  y  1.7


# Wanted: using pd.NA by default, not NaN.
```

In particular, if I would convert the result of that expression after the fact, the `a` column has already been converted to float (to use NaN as the missing marker), which is a bit unfortunate.

(As of this writing, pd.NA is still experimental - but I would like to opt-in).

Comment: You have to do the dtype change after `from_records` : ``df.astype({"a":"Int64", "c":"Int64"})`` or use `convert_dtypes` : ``df.convert_dtypes()``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned @sammywemmy in comments, possible solution is add code after `from_records`, e.g. [`DataFrame.convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    {'a': 1, 'b': 'x'},
    {'b': 'y', 'c': 1.7},
])

    
print (df.convert_dtypes())
      a  b     c
0     1  x  <NA>
1  <NA>  y   1.7

print (df.convert_dtypes().dtypes)
a      Int64
b     string
c    Float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to that, it does the job. I'm not 100% happy to do the conversion after the fact (after conversion to float and then back) - what do you think of something like this for the same job? It looks convoluted, admittedly. It takes a list of dicts. `pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(r, index=pd.RangeIndex(1)).convert_dtypes() for r in records]).reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Watch the Float and Int conversions when using ```df.convert_dtypes()``` use ```convert_floating=False``` parameter to get Int. Maybe use ```df.convert_dtypes()``` in a targeted way when converting.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    {'a': 1, 'b': 'x'},
    {'b': 'y', 'c': 1.7},
])

df.fillna(pd.NA, inplace=True)
```

Comment: The columns are still using the "legacy" types here, not Int64/Float64 etc.